# How do I assign index values to a level of Multi index Data Frame?

Tags: pandas

I have a Multi index Data Frame. However, I wanted to change its first level to a certain list of index values. Suppose its first level is initially `[2,4,1]`, I want to change it to `[1,2,100]`. What is the simplest way to achieve it? My current approach would involve, reset_index, change column values and set index again.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a dictionary of the old values to the replacement values, then iterate through the index as tuples replacing the values, and assign the new index back to the DataFrame:

```
new_vals = {2: 1, 4: 2, 1: 100}
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(new_vals[tup[0]], tup[1]) for tup in df.index.to_list()])
```

(This assumes your MultiIndex has only 2 levels, for every additional level that you want to keep you'd need to add `tup[2]` etc into the list comprehension.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.reindex()`

```
data.reindex([1,2,100])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename):

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(e, i) for i, e in enumerate([2, 4, 1])])
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], index=index)

print(df)
```

**Output** *(of setup)*

```
     0
2 0  1
4 1  2
1 2  3
```

**Code**

```
new_index = [1, 2, 100]
new_vals = dict(zip(df.index.levels[0], new_index))
print(df.rename(new_vals, level=0))
```

**Output**

```
       0
1   0  1
2   1  2
100 2  3
```